# Saving what is currently drawn into a view as an image

Tags: cocoa-touch, drawing

I am creating a drawing app and have run into a problem. I have an array of curves; each curve keeps an array of points, and each point keeps its color, thickness, and coords.

When I `drawRect:` is called, I redraw all the curves from this array. The problem is that this array is getting huge, and the app slows down.

My idea is to, at the end of each redrawing, save the current context as an image, free the curves array, and at the next redraw, use that image as the background. Ultimately, I don't need the curves array at all, just an array of the curves in progress. Is this possible? Or maybe there is another way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can render the corresponding layer of your view as image to update in on the next iteration. Sure it is better in this case to use `UIImageView` as yourViewToSaveAsImage. In this case you could get this process even easier...

```
UIView *view = yourViewToSaveAsImage;

UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(view.bounds.size);
[view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *result = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Comment: Am i right that i need to add only UIGraphicsGetImage... if i have already set context etc?

Comment: if you mean drawRect - yes. But again, if your view will be an instance of UIImageView, you will get this image for free

Answer (score 0):

A path contains only information on points, so if you want to track variations in rendering you need a separate list of objects.

I achieved this by creating an `NSArray*` of my own custom objects that included fields such as: an `NSBezierPath*` (to capture the points and simplify drawing the segment), a `CGPathDrawingMode` to use for the segment, and information on the color and line size.

Then when I draw, I iterate over the elements of the array, set the context's current colors, and call either `stroke` or `fill` on the current element's `NSBezierPath*` depending on how I configured that segment.

I would also like to know if there's a faster way but this approach certainly works well.

Comment: Yep I am doing the same(almost). I get slow perfomance after i added number of lines :s

Comment: I do not create an element for every line; as long as a line connects to another line of the same color, line width, etc. I coalesce all of those segments into a single `NSBezierPath*`.  Also, I don't store a count of lines; the path and array length can be used to infer it.